# Cleaning Float Column of Longitude

Tags: python, pandas

I am cleaning a dataset where columns lat and long are presenting some values multiplied by 10. Not only 10, but changing 10^n. I wrote the code below. I am not sure if it is the best way, but is working. May you help me?

I will put this code inside a function, so do not bother you creating a function at all. I just need other opinions on how to deal with this task.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

accidents = pd.DataFrame([0, -5197, -5114758, np.NaN, -512281, -51.116024, -51.213559, -51.227893], columns=['longitude'])
    
def clean_geo(df_raw: pd.DataFrame, col: str, coord: int) -> pd.Series:
    """This function will fill values that a geopoint
    with NaN and transform the remaning. It is designer to
    coordenates with 2 digits before dot."""
    temp = df_raw[col].copy()

    mask = temp.astype("str").str[0:2] != str(coord)[:2]  # Picking number outside the coordenate

    temp[mask] = np.NaN

    temp2 = temp[~mask].astype("str").str[:3] + "." + temp[~mask].astype("str").str[4:-2]

    temp[~mask] = temp2.astype("float")
    
    return temp

accidents["longitude"] = clean_geo(accidents, "longitude", -51)

accidents["longitude"].describe()
```

I tried to write something with apply and lambda, but I failed and I am not sure if it is good choice, considering that on my way I use the vectoring/forecasting power of pandas/numpy.

Comment: This assumes a very specific kind of accident: that there are entries where the decimal point has been substituted for some digit. How is that possible in practical terms? Are these figures entered by keyboard?

Comment: @Reinderien, I do not believe that this data is manually imputed. However, what I am seeing is this. On my example, I generalize the situation, but this is the situation. Some entries are fine (-51.xyz) and others has many different values beginning with -51 (i.e. 51,000,998.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc-comment doesn't really tell me what this function is doing.  Some of that is grammar and spelling, but it's absolutely unclear what kind of "transform" it's doing.  And while we can guess what the first two arguments mean from their names, the last is utterly opaque.

I think this is what the code does:

```
"""
Return a copy of column COL from DF_RAW modified as follows:

For each value, if it can be divided by an exact power of
ten to make it fall between COORD and COORD+1, then do so,
else replace with NaN.
"""
```

That already exposes one problem with the approach: it won't work for regions which straddle a 1-degree meridian line.  We'll have to invoke the function twice (or more) for such areas.  (Actually, we'll have to combine the two results, rather than just applying the function sequentially.)

I think the approach is flawed: instead of working with strings, we should be looking at the *numeric* values, and provide a range of longitudes considered valid.

Sticking with the string approach for the moment, we have some assumptions built in.  When I tried passing  `-5.122`, I got an exception.  That's because the test `!= str(coord)[:2]` is inconsistent with the assumption made in the rest of the function that `coord` has three characters.  We should be measuring its *actual* length and using that.

With the code shown, I got corruption of the transformed values:

```
     original   cleaned
0         0.0       NaN
1     -5197.0     -51.7
2  -5114758.0  -51.4758
3         nan       NaN
4   -512281.0   -51.281
5  -51.116024  -51.1160
6  -51.213559  -51.2135
7  -51.227893  -51.2278
8      -5.122       NaN
```

Notice the missing `9` in row 1, and the missing `1` in row 2, etc.  We're *replacing* a digit with `.`, instead of *inserting*.

We should be using a main-guard for the code outside of the function, to make this importable as a module.

The `describe()` result is unused, so we should either print it or remove it.

---

## Modified code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

accidents = pd.DataFrame([0, -5197, -5114758, np.NaN, -512281,
                          -51.116024, -51.213559, -51.227893, -5.122],
                         columns=['longitude'])
    
def clean_geo(series: pd.Series, coord: int) -> pd.Series:
    """
    Return a copy of SERIES with each element modified by inserting a
    decimal point if necessary to make its integer part be COORD, or
    replaced with NaN if that is not possible.
    """
    longitudes = series.copy()

    i_len = len(str(coord))     # length of integer part

    mask = longitudes.astype("str").str[:i_len] != str(coord)
    longitudes[mask] = np.NaN

    strings = longitudes[~mask].astype("str")
    strings = (strings.str[:i_len] + "." +
               strings.str[i_len:].str.replace('.', '', regex=False))
    longitudes[~mask] = strings.astype("float")

    return longitudes


if __name__ == '__main__':
    accidents["longitude"] = clean_geo(accidents["longitude"], -51)
    print(accidents)
    print(accidents["longitude"].describe())
```

Comment: I made some changes, but I will incorporate some of your tips. I also see add protection to extreme values, outside (-53, -49), i.e.. I used a Series.between() to pick these rows and fill them with np.NaN. I am coming from Kaggle and this is my first time using an IDE. This is why I do not use the main-guard. In truth, I need to learn more about it.